# yesod book basic forms - compilation error

Tags: haskell, yesod

I did a fresh install of yesod (cabal install yesod) and tried the form-example on page http://www.yesodweb.com/book/forms where the custom field is used. Compiler gives errors on data constructor and functions not in scope.

See http://hpaste.org/49690 for code and error-list. How is this solved?

When running from scaffolded project, I get the same errors...

Comment: What version of yesod-form do you have installed? Is the error message any different if you add a `import Yesod.Form` line?

Comment: No differences when adding Yesod.Form.
Installed version is 0.1.0.1.
Cabal output:
    Default available version: 0.2.0.1
    Installed versions: 0.1.0.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These appears to be errors in the example, caused by missing `import` statements.

You'll need to import these modules:

- `Control.Monad` for `mplus`.
- `Data.Maybe` for `fromMaybe`.
- `Safe` for `readMay` (from the [safe](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/safe/0.3/doc/html/Safe.html) package).
- `Yesod.Form.Core` for `newFormIdent`, `askParams` and the `GForm` constructor.

Having fixed that, another error appears:

```
FormSuccess (Params min max single plural)
```

should be

```
FormSuccess (Params (min, max) single plural)
```

I got it to run with these changes on Yesod 0.8.2.1 (with yesod-form-0.1.0.1)